# How to perform operations on a selected piece of string after regex in clojure

Tags: regex, clojure

Base String:

```
SELECT (sum([column.one]) / sum([column.two])) AS [sum / sum], [column.three] AS [column.three] FROM [database.table] GROUP BY [column.three] ORDER BY [column.three] ASC
```

Resultant String:

```
SELECT (sum([column.one]) / sum([column.two])) AS [sum___sum], [column.three] AS [column.three] FROM [database.table] GROUP BY [column.three] ORDER BY [column.three] ASC
```

Here `[sum / sum]` could change to some other format like `[sum * distinct]` or `[max + min - distinct]`

---

What I have till now:

Replace all the values with `[]` around them with _:

`(s/replace sql #"\[(.*?)\]" "_")`

What I am trying:
If I can get the value that got matched, I can replace all special characters except dot (.) with an underscore.

`(s/replace sql #"\[(.*?)\]" #(s/replace "$1" #"[\/\*\-\+\(\)\\\s]" "_"))`

More clarity:
In short, anything inside `[]` can only be a combination of alphanumeric, dots, and underscores. Otherwise replace that character with underscore (_).

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question. Is it always the thing after the first AS that you wish to change? Should it always be `[sum___sum]`?

Comment: Updated more details to questions. @AlanThompson

Comment: in this case "$1" is not a valid syntax. you should operate the match passed by first replace in the second one. Just replace "$1" with `(second %)`

Comment: Manipulating SQL as strings is not safe compared to an ORM or prepared statements.

Comment: @tar: I understand that, but sometimes you gotta take that risk. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks @leetwinski. If you can add that as answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Re "More clarity:", when that is no so, what should it be replaced with?

Comment: @AlanThompson Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Repeating my answer from comments]

In this case "$1" is not a valid syntax. 
You are trying to replace something in literal string "$1", not in the matched string. You should operate the match passed by first replace in the second one. Just replace "$1" with `(second %)`

Answer (score 0):

Ugly way would be simple line splitting with `subs` to first part and second part. Then add you "sum___sum" between those parts.

That would be quite simple if part to be replaced is always first "AS [" in your sql query string. You can use that to find right `index-of` from your string. That way you wouldn't need the regexp.

As mentioned earlier inserting string straight to the query might offer possibility to attack into your database using sql injection.

Better way would be use parameter(s) in your original query or create the query as a prepared statement.